# inconsistent accessibility error in C# interface implementation

Tags: c#

At first, I have gone over similar questions already, but i still think my problem is something different.:)

I have an interface :

```
namespace TEDLibrary
{
    public interface ILogWriter
    {
        void WriteLog(ILogRecord log);
    }
}
```

and i have an implementation class :

```
namespace TEDLibrary
{
    public class LogWriter : ILogWriter
    {
        public LogWriter()
        { 

        }

        public void WriteLog(ILogRecord log)
        { 

        }
    }
}
```

As you see classes and members are **public** already.

However i get

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'TEDLibrary.ILogRecord' is
>   less accessible than method
>   'TEDLibrary.ILogWriter.WriteLog(TEDLibrary.ILogRecord)'

I tried to declare WriteLog method in interface as public but it is not allowed.

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? It tells you *exactly* what needs to be made public: `ILogRecord`, which you haven't shown here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ILogRecord` should be public too.